# ES6 import all files in a folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6

How can I import all files in a folder using ES6 modules tools?

need something like:

```
files.forEach(function (file){
  import * as object from 'file';
}};
```

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do with these imported files? The short answer is "that won't work" with ES6 module syntax but it's hard to give more meaningful feedback with no other info to go on.

Comment: If you want to  migrate current project with many modules, amd you lookin for fast&dirty solution, try use require():

/**
 * Requires all directives from subdirectories.
 */
function requireAll(requireContext) {
    return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}
requireAll(require.context("<path to sub dir>", true, /^\.\/.*\.js$/));
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343362/integrate-ecmascript-6-into-existing-angularjs-project

Comment: I'm just trying create one npm package, which will manipulate users modules. I can know the folder were will be all the modules, but i can't now files and variables names.